# Visual Basic for Excel Run-time error '-214747848 (80010108)': Method '_Default' of object 'Range' failed -- only for some fields

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm creating a automated data entry user form in excel to track various jobs.

I followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P53T6oxgUVA) however, I keep getting this error.

I only get the error on some of the entry fields and can't figure out what I did wrong.

I started with the "Reset" code:

```vb
Sub Reset()

    Dim iRow As Long
    
    iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] 'identifying the last row
    
    With frmForm
    
        .cmbStatus.Clear
        
        .cmbStatus.AddItem "Accepted"
        .cmbStatus.AddItem "Declined"
        .cmbStatus.AddItem "Canceled"
        .cmbStatus.AddItem "Sent"
        
        
        .txtOwner.Value = ""
        .txtPOC.Value = ""
        .txtPhone.Value = ""
        .txtAddress.Value = ""
        
        .cmbCounty.Clear
        
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Bedford"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Brentwood"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Cannon"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Cheatham"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Cheatham/Davidson"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Cheatham/Robertson"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Coffee"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Columbia"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Davidson"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Davidson/Williamson"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Decatur"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Dekalb"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Dickson"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Fairview"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Franklin"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Giles"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Hickman"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Houston"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Humphreys"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Lawrence"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Lewis"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Lincoln"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Lyles"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Marshall"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Maury"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Montgomery"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Mufreesboro"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Perry"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Robertson"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Rutherford"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Sevier"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Spring Hill"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Stewart"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Sumner"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Sumner/Millersville"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Thompsons Station"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Wayne"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "White"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Williamson"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Williamson/Cheatham"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Williamson/Maury"
        .cmbCounty.AddItem "Wilson"
        
        
        .cmbType.Clear
        
        .cmbType.AddItem "1 lot sub"
        .cmbType.AddItem "2 lot sub"
        .cmbType.AddItem "2 lot sub/stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "3 lot sub"
        .cmbType.AddItem "4 lot sub"
        .cmbType.AddItem "5 acre division"
        .cmbType.AddItem "ALTA"
        .cmbType.AddItem "ALTA/Boundary/Topo/SSDS"
        .cmbType.AddItem "ALTA/SSDS"
        .cmbType.AddItem "As Built"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Beer Permit Distance Letter"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary "
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary Partial "
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Combination"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Division"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Division/SSDS"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Division/Subdivision"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Easment"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/FEC"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/FEC/Site Plan"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Grid"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Grid/SSDS"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Grid/SSDS/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Grid/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/HPR"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Legal"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Legal/SSDS/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Legal/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Plat"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Plat/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Redivision"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Site Plan"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Site Plan/SSDS"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/SSDS"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/SSDS/Stake/Subdivision"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/SSDS/Subdivision"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Subdivision"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Topo"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Topo/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Boundary/Topo/Tree ID"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Combine"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Construction"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Distance Letter"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Division"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Division/Site Plan"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Division/SSDS"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Division/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Draft"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Easement"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Easement/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "ELOMA"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Erosion Site Plan"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Feasability"
        .cmbType.AddItem "FEC"
        .cmbType.AddItem "FEC/Site Plan"
        .cmbType.AddItem "FEC/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "FEC/Stake/Topo"
        .cmbType.AddItem "FEC/Topo"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Flood Elevation"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Foundation"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Grid"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Grid Map"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Grid Map/SSDS"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Grid/Site Plan"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Grid/SSDS"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Grid/SSDS/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Grid/SSDS/Topo"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Grid/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "HPR"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Legal"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Legal/Subdivision"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Line Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "LLP"
        .cmbType.AddItem "LOMA"
        .cmbType.AddItem "LOMA/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Pin"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Plat"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Plat/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Recertify"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Redivision"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Redivision/SSDS"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Research"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Revision"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Rezone and Divide"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Site Plan"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Site Plan "
        .cmbType.AddItem "Site Plan Pin"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Site Plan/Grid"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Site Plan/LIDAR"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Site Plan/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Site Plan/Stake/Topo"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Site Plan/Subdivision"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Site Plan/Topo"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Sketch Plan"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Split"
        .cmbType.AddItem "SSDS"
        .cmbType.AddItem "ssds "
        .cmbType.AddItem "SSDS/Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "SSDS/Subdivision"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Stake"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Stake "
        .cmbType.AddItem "Stake Site Plan"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Stake Subdivision"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Stake Subdivision "
        .cmbType.AddItem "Stake/Subdivision"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Streamline"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Subdivision"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Subdivision Major"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Subdivision/Plat"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Subdivision/Topo"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Surveyors Report"
        .cmbType.AddItem "tminor sub"
        .cmbType.AddItem "Topo"

       
        .txtPrice.Value = ""
        .txtIntake.Value = ""
        .txtQuoted.Value = ""
        .txtFollowUp.Value = ""
        
        .lstDatabase.ColumnCount = 11
        .lstDatabase.ColumnHeads = True
        
        .lstDatabase.ColumnWidths = "30,75,75,60,100,60,60,60,60,60,60"
        
        If iRow > 1 Then
            .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:K" & iRow
        Else
            .lstDatabase.RowSource = "Database!A2:K2"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Then I added the Submit code. The first ".Cell" is where it takes me when I "debug" the error.

```vb
Sub Submit()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    
    iRow = ([Counta(Database!A:A)] + 1)
    
    With sh
        .Cells(iRow, 1) = frmForm.cmbStatus.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 2) = frmForm.txtOwner.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 3) = frmForm.txtPOC.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 4) = frmForm.txtPhone.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 5) = frmForm.txtAddress.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 6) = frmForm.cmbCounty.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 7) = frmForm.cmbType.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 8) = frmForm.txtPrice.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 9) = frmForm.txtIntake.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 10) = frmForm.txtQuoted.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 11) = frmForm.txtFollowUp.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Although it gives me this error, it still saved the data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `iRow` when this error happens?

Comment: @FunThomas it is 3234 every time. For both the data that works and doesn't work.  Its a very large database

Comment: Try this:  
    lRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Comment: @PeterT That seemed to work, however it is saving them them at the top and deleting entries

Comment: rngCell.End(xlUp).Row returns the first non-empty cell above rngCell, and with .Row its row. You want the first empty cell below it hence the +1.  If when you write to this row existing data is replaced, that would indicate you have non-empty cells to the right and perhaps below this empty cell. Solution, change the "A" in "A65536" to any column in the data you know contains the last record.